# Debug into Maven Dependency Source w/IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, maven, intellij-idea, crawler4j

I'm debugging a Maven project in IntelliJ and I'm trying to figure out how to step into the source of one of my dependencies that's specified in my pom.xml.  Specifically, my project has a dependency on Crawler4J I'm seeing some weird behaviour from Parser.parse(), and I want to step thru that method.  I tried setting up a local cloned Git repo with the source and attaching it via the Sources option under Project Structure, but I still can't step into the compiled Crawler4J methods.  As a long time C# developer (and relative Java nub) what I would have ideally liked is something like .NET Reflector's functionality for decompiling on the fly while debugging, but a way to attach the source would suffice.

Comment: With IntelliJ's maven support you can download and attach the sources on-the-fly - this should work out of the box. Did you import the project as a maven project (so that Idea nows about the pom)?

Comment: Oh, and you can also [decompile](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7100) but downloading the original sources is a better approach for maven artifacts.

Comment: Thanks!  You're correct, as the answer below indicates as well.  I appreciate the help.  The decompile pointer may come in handy at some point as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just set up the same dependency and I have no problems to download the source code.

[image]

Now I created a simple Main class with a Parser. I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left-click and it will bring me to the  Parser class.

[image]

As you can see it has a link in the upper right corner saying `Download Sources`.

[image]

After pressing that link the sources are downloaded and immediately available.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too.  For some reason I wasn't initially shown the "Download Sources" option.  Appreciate the help!